# Unable to set FormulaArray property of the Range class - How to shorten with variables

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this script (I made a base macro then proceeded to edit it to do everything I needed), which works perfectly except for the last 2 formulas, which are too big for FormulaArray to work with. I believe the limit is 255, and these formulas are around 260 with spaces.

```
Sub Expenses2()
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ID"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Names"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Weekend"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Team Leader"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 1"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1 £"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 2"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2 £"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 3"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3 £"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 4"
Range("L1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4 £"
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 5"
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5 £"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='PSC Audit Report 3.0'!RC"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('p:\_new P Drive_\accounts department\myname\[Customer Date - ID & Name.xls]Customer Data'!R2C3:R30000C3,MATCH(RC[-1],'P:\_NEW P DRIVE_\ACCOUNTS DEPARTMENT\myname\[Customer Data - ID & Name.xls]Customer Data'!R2C2:R30000C2,0))"
    Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='PSC Audit Report 3.0'!RC[-1]"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='PSC Audit Report 3.0'!RC[-1]"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!R1C4:R1C46,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!RC[-1]:RC[41]>0,),0))"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,),0))"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2),0))"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2),0))"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2),0))"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2),0))"
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2),0))"
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2),0))"
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>L2),0))"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0,)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2)*('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>L2),0))"
```

End Sub

I've changed this to this:

```
Sub Expenses()
'
' Expenses Macro
 '
Dim sAudit As String
sAudit = "PSC Audit Report 3.0"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ID"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Names"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Weekend"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Team Leader"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 1"
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1 £"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 2"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2 £"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 3"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3 £"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 4"
Range("L1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4 £"
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expense 5"
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5 £"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='sAudit'!RC"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('p:\_new P Drive_\accounts department\steven mack\[Customer Date - ID & Name.xls]Customer Data'!R2C3:R30000C3,MATCH(RC[-1],'P:\_NEW P DRIVE_\ACCOUNTS DEPARTMENT\Steven Mack\[Customer Data - ID & Name.xls]Customer Data'!R2C2:R30000C2,0))"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='sAudit'!RC[-1]"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='sAudit'!RC[-1]"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('sAudit'!R1C4:R1C46,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('sAudit'!RC[-1]:RC[41]>0,),0))"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,),0))"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2),0))"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2),0))"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2),0))"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2),0))"
Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>J2),0))"
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>J2),0))"
Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!$D$1:$AT$1,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>J2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>L2),0))"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2,MATCH(1,INDEX('sAudit'!D2:AT2>0,)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>F2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>H2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>J2)*('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>L2),0))"
```

End Sub

However all of my formulas just end up with sAudit in them instead of PSC Audit Report 3.0 in them. :/

Additionally, not something that's a problem with these, but for cells A2 to N2, it keeps opening a window to select another file. I can click cancel every time but it's bloody annoying. Anyone come across this before?

Comment: You need to *concatenate* the variable value into the formula, not put the literal variable name in: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & sAudit & "'!RC"`. This won't help with your original issue though!

Comment: I'm sure I did something like that the first time around from googling, but it wasn't working. I think I had the apostrophes as part of the sAudit string though, which might have been why it didn't work.

However this is still giving me the same error. It's still too long. If I create more variables for ('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>J2) & ('sAudit'!D2:AT2<>L2), that should do it though. 

Thanks for the help Rory, I should be fine from here I hope.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use non-array formulas for the last two:

```
Range("M2").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>L2),'PSC Audit Report 3.0'!$D$1:$AT$1)"
Range("N2").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2>0)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>F2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>H2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>J2)/('PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2<>L2),'PSC Audit Report 3.0'!D2:AT2)"
```

Comment: Did not know I could do it that way. Much easier! Cheers. :D

Comment: I'm using your Lookup formula for another sheet, basically doing the same thing as I was doing on my original sheet up top, but I'm pulling data from vertical columns rather than rows. From my understanding of Lookup, this should work, but I for some reason it's only taking the last from the column, no matter what:

    `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200=$B$1)/('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200<>A4)/('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200<>A5),'May 16'!$A$3:$A$200),1)`

Can you advise what's wrong with this?

Comment: Not without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: Column J holds collection dates. Cell B1=17/06/16, or whatever date I want to pull clients for. Column A holds IDs. Everything will be pulled from a database based off of their ID, which works fine. Right now I'm looking to pull 12~ clients that have collection dates set for 17/06/16, and the formulas, which I've done 4 times like above, are all pulling the lowest ID in the range in column J. I hope this is enough information. There isn't really anything else that is relevant I believe.

Comment: I don't get the formula then. You test J against B1 and also against A4 and A5 - what's in those two cells and what's the point of that test?

Comment: Sorry for not making things clear enough. I'm testing B1 against Column J on sheet May 16, which has all my data for clients that owe fees. Column A on sheet May 16, has the customer ID from the clients. The test is meant to pull every person who has a collection date in column J that is the same as B1, onto a separate sheet. The part of the formula with <>A4 & <>A5 is to stop multiples being brought forward.   This is basically doing the exact same thing my script does above, except instead of searching horizontally along D2:AT2, I'm searching vertically in column J.

Comment: Sorry, A4 & A5 have similar formulas:  
    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(B1,('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200),'May 16'!$A$3:$A$200),1)  
    =IFERROR(LOOKUP(B1,('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200)/('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200<>A4),'May 16'!$A$3:$A$200),1)  
However, I realised why it wasn't working. In my original script at the very top, I was testing against the £ amounts that had previously been put in a cell. In this test, I'm pitting it against the cell where I put a unique ID, which means the formulas above will always pass that test. I can't test against the date, as they all share the same date.... I've stumped myself.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. That looks like A4 returns a customer ID.

Comment: You're right, it does return an ID. It took me over an hour to realise that. So A5 formula searches column J on sheet May 16 for anyone with the date 17/06/16. It then compares that date to what is in cell A4, however cell A4 isn't a date, it's the ID. Which essentially makes the formulas above all irrelevant, because they don't work in this situation. I guess I need to compare the ID's to each other while searching column J for the date in B1. I'm so sorry I waste your time Rory, I don't believe the original formulas I put up in this conversation are feasible to work here.

Comment: Can't you just adjust them to compare col A on 'May 16' to exclude the ID you already found?

Comment: That was my first thought, and I tried this formula in A5, but it doesn't work. `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(B1,('May 16'!$J$3:$J$200)/('May 16'!$A$3:$A$200<>A4),'May 16'!$A$3:$A$200),1)` Perhaps I don't understand how it works fully. I'll have to give it a mess around on Friday.

Comment: You need the lookup(2,1/... Syntax

Comment: I did try that syntax but I got an error. Perhaps I had some of the other bits wrong. I'm out of work now but I'll try it all out on Friday. Thanks very much for the patience and help today.